# Windows 10 Bluetooth Advertisement API

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10

Is it possible to use an AdvertisementPublisher to send a major and minor ID when acting as a beacon, and is it also possible to use an AdvertisementWatcher to send and receive the ID?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, do this to send:

```
var manufacturerData = new BluetoothLEManufacturerData();

manufacturerData.CompanyId = 0x004c;

byte[] dataArray = new byte[] {
    // last 2 bytes of Apple's iBeacon
    0x02, 0x15,
    // Proximity UUID
    0x44, 0x50, 0x3f, 0x1b,
    0xc0, 0x9c, 0x4a, 0xee,
    0x97, 0x2f, 0x75, 0x0e,
    0x9d, 0x34, 0x67, 0x84,
    // Major
    0x00, 0x01,
    // Minor
    0x00, 0x10,
    // TX power
    0xc5
};

// using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
manufacturerData.Data = dataArray.AsBuffer();

BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher publisher =
    new BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher();

publisher.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(manufacturerData);

publisher.Start();
```

To receive, go to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505227/can-i-read-an-iphone-beacon-with-windows-devices-bluetooth-advertisement-bluetoo).